# Node works differently with using launch file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for my mistakes. English is not my native language. I created a node, that subscribes to topic with data from sensors, then find with tf::TransformListener and tf::StampedTransform robot position, combines this data and writes it in csv file, also it prints in terminal robot position. Then I run this code with rosrun everything works as it should work, but then I run it with roslaunch it only prints position in the terminal with no data written in file. Appreciate any help.
This is how looks my launch file

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
     <node pkg="minicar_current_pose" type="minicar_current_pose_node" name="minicar_current_pose_node"  output="screen">
</node>
</launch>
```

---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408167/node-works-differently-with-using-launch-file./) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default in linux, the current working directory for roslaunch is `$HOME/.ros/`. If you did not specify a full path when you opened the file, the file was probably created there.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-19**:
Thank you for your help. You are right, I found it there